# why does my code not work when I simply add "export" in front of my class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript code:

```
export class GridObject {
  constructor() {
    alert("hello from GridObject constructor!");
  }
}

var go = new GridObject();
```

I'm calling the compiled js from my HTML. When I remove "export", the alert shows up, and it doesn't when I have "export".

The following is the entire compiled js when using export

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var GridObject = /** @class */ (function () {
  function GridObject() {
    alert("hello from GridObject constructor!");
  }
  return GridObject;
}());
exports.GridObject = GridObject;
var go = new GridObject();
```

removing export from the TS removes the following 3 lines from the JS

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;

exports.GridObject = GridObject;
```

My HTML calls this script like this:

```
<script src="GridObject.js"></script>
```

I tried adding type="module" but that didn't work either.

Comment: That's because `export` is for JS modules. And it should be loaded in a different way https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

Comment: The compiled JS doesn't actually have the "export" keyword.

Comment: What does the error message say in the browser console? Is it something like "VM56:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" ?

Comment: In chrome, right click and select inspect or press `ctrl+i`

Comment: @artem Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at GridObject.js:2

Comment: May I ask why you added the `export` keyword?

Comment: @maxpelic because I was writing some code that got a bit messy, so I wanted to split it up into separate files. Specifically 1 file for each class.

Comment: @AnthonyYershov so that's the reason - the compiled code throws an exception which prevents the line with `new GridObject()` from being executed. The exception is thrown because that's what browsers do when `"use strict";` is declared and there's a reference to undeclared global object. `exports` is undeclared because it's a `node.js` specific global, which is absent in the browser. The compiled code is referencing `node.js`-specific `exports`  global probably because the compilation target is `CommonJS`.

Comment: The typical way to split code into modules and then use it in the browser is to use some kind of module bundler like webpack.

Comment: So I googled the error msg and I found an answer that worked! All I had to do was type in <script>var exports = {};</script> before JS references. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined

Comment: @AnthonyYershov if you target pre-ES2015, then how exactly it exports a symbol to the global space depends on the compiler configuration. Just open the compiled file and check what it does.

Comment: @zerkms vs code underlines 'exports' and gives the following tool-tip: File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module.ts(80001). Is this what you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7576001/251311