# Requiring bundled module by browserify in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, browserify

How to import/inject npm module/package bundled with browserify into AngularJS module?

```
angular.module('name', ['packagename'])
```

&

```
angular.module('name', [require('packagename')])
```

Both gives error saying module not found. But it is there in **bundle.js**(bundle created by browserify).

Comment: This is correct..
angular.module('name', ['packagename'])
However, I am not sure your bundler is actually adding it to the bundle

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you went to wrong way.

> Browserify is a tool for compiling node-flavored commonjs modules for the browser.

There is no reason to put Browserify inside Angularjs, AngularjS is a client.

It is like to put react native `babel` or `webpack`.

---

About `angular.module('name', ['packagename'])`

To import any module to your project, check that the module has:

```
angular.module('packagename', ['ng']). ...
```

For example https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate/2.5.0/angular-translate.js

has `angular.module('pascalprecht.translate', ['ng']).run(/* ... */)`

Generally, you can find in DOCs that the module supports Angularjs.

Comment: There are some packages used having 'module.exports' in the project which are usually used in NodeJs. That's why browserify is used.

Comment: There are some packages used having 'module.exports' in the project which are usually used in NodeJs. That's why browserify is used.

Comment: @Anuj, well, NodeJs runs on backend, it is not related to the client that runs statics + JS on client-side. You try to integrate in client something that manipulates with code like webpack

Comment: maybe this one will give you some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576001/how-to-require-commonjs-modules-in-the-browser