# Cannot access before initialization using Node JS and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have three js files as below

*index.js*

```
function getNumberToDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("currentDay").innerHTML = getNumber();
}
```

*checkDay.js*

```
const randomDate = require("./randomDate");
module.exports = {};
function getNumber(){
    return randomDate.getSmallNumber();
}
module.exports.getNumber = getNumber;
```

*randomDate.js*

```
module.exports = {};
function getSmallNumber(){
    return 3;
}
module.exports.getSmallNumber = getSmallNumber;
```

I also have a html page which has a button which calls the getNumberToDisplay function. All 3 scripts are included in the html page by using the  tags. When I press the button to call getNumberToDisplay I get the error *Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'randomDate' before initialization*

What is it that I am missing in order to be able to get the button to execute the function? The tests of the functions return the expected results in Jest, but the button doesn't work when opening the html page in Chrome.

Comment: this is not javascript, it looks more like nodejs. This won't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576001/how-can-i-require-commonjs-modules-in-the-browser

Comment: Ah, I have been using Jest to test the code, I have created the above simple code to just replicate the problem. Is there a way to make this work without using server to host the code? Can Chrome handle node natively?